# Change task placement strategy of Amazon ECS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have about 15 micro-services running in a single ECS cluster with 5 EC2 instances. While setting up the services I did not pay too much attention to the task placement strategy and now I want to change it, but so far I have not found a way to do so. 
It seems to be that you can only define the strategy when creating a service, not when updating it (the Amazon documentation doesn't mention it for updating but it doesn't say it's impossible either).

Is there a way to change the Task Placement or do I have to re-create every service ?

Comment: There is no way to update the task placement strategy after creating service, I think you need to recreate all the services

Answer (score 1):

You can only update the deployment configuration after creating an ECS service, i.e. minimumHealthyPercent and maximumPercent, see [the API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateService.html).

Thus, if you want to change the placement strategy, you have to re-create the service.

Answer (score 0):

Actually https://serverfault.com/users/265350/m-glatki, there are 2 ways, not one.

Per documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-strategies.html), you can define a placement strategy with:

- CreateService (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateService.html)
- RunTask (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html)